# 413 error after deploying to app service .Net Core 3.1, React

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-appservice

I have an API which allows to upload pdf files. if I try to upload file which is more than 30mb it is throwing error "IIS7 413error" in azure logs. But the same code works when I run through postman. I have these attributes in my code`[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit =209715200)] [RequestSizeLimit(209715200)] [DisableRequestSizeLimit()]` but that won't help after deployment. Also if I need to change anything on the frontend side i'm not sure, any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding these configuration - refered this link  `enter code here`https://www.ryadel.com/en/http-error-413-request-entity-too-large-fix/

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```